Existence and uniqueness of equilibrium points for concave n-person games
I hope you are doing well.
I am reading Rosen's paper.
I am having a difficulty in understanding the following statements on page 530

The set $U(x) \subset E^k$ is determined as follows:
$$
U(x)=\left\{u \mid\|f(x, u, \bar{r})\|=\min _{\substack{v_j \geqslant 0, j \in J \\ v_j=0, j \notin J}}\|f(x, v, \bar{r})\|\right\},
$$
where
(4.6) $J=J(x)=\left\{j \mid h_j(x) \leqslant 0\right\}$.
Note that for every interior point $x$ of $R$ the set $J(x)$ is empty and $U(x)=0$, so that $f(x, u, \bar{r})=g(x, \bar{r})$, for every interior point of $R$.

I don't understand why $U(x) =0$. On the other hand, why $J(x)$ is empty when $x$ is an interior point of $x$ of $R$.
Thank you for your time and consideration.
